# how to give transparency to button background in android

Tags: android, xml, button

I want button to have certain level of transparency in background . I am using

```
android:alpha="0.7"
```

to give transparency to button but the problem is the text of the button is also fading accordingly . I don't want text of the button to fade here is my code

**xml file**

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/butbday"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:alpha="0.7"
                android:background="#0099CC"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bday"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**java file**

```
String txtBday = "<big> <font color='#FFFFFF'>"
                + "Birthday & Anniversary" + "</font> </big>" + "<br />" 
                + "<small><font color='#FFFFFF'>" + "Invite all those who are ready for party today" + "</small>";

but_bday.setText(Html.fromHtml(txtBday));
```

Comment: `android:background="#800099CC"`, 80 at the start will give 50 transparency.

Comment: Change this android:background="#0099CC" to android:background="#AA0099CC". :) You can try various options from (00 - FF) instead of AA. Suit yourself.

Comment: Just to prevent any confusion, hex has a range of 00 - FF (0 to 255)

Comment: My Bad. Thanks :) Corrected myself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give transparency in Android just use these codes at start of your # code accordingly:

For example to make a view 50% transparent use:

```
android:background="#80000000"
```

*Please note the 80 at the start*

```
100% — FF
95% — F2
90% — E6
85% — D9
80% — CC
75% — BF
70% — B3
65% — A6
60% — 99
55% — 8C
50% — 80
45% — 73
40% — 66
35% — 59
30% — 4D
25% — 40
20% — 33
15% — 26
10% — 1A
5% — 0D
0% — 00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/butbday"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"   <! -- this does it for me -->
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bday"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create hex colors with the alpha channel. To get .7 alpha, try `#B30099CC1` (`#B3` = 179 which is ~ 70% of 255)